# create nested class (kt) for existing class (java), extensions

Tags: kotlin, nested, extension-methods, inner-classes

does Kotlin compiler allow extending classes with inner and/or nested classes and if so what's the correct syntax?

in *EnclosingClass.java*

```
class EnclosingJavaClass {
    class NestedJavaClass1 {}
    class NestedJavaClass2 {}
    // ...
}
```

this is what i'm unsure of below,

in *EnclosingClassExtensions.kt*

```
class EnclosingJavaClass.NestedKotlinClass {
    // ...
}
```

assuming that `EnclosingClass.java` cannot be modified (eg: library code), can i declare somehow a `EnclosingClass.SomeNewKotlinClass` ?

Comment: The fact that the class has nested classes doesn't change anything to how you add extension functions: `fun EnclosingJavaClass.someExtensionFunction() { ... }`. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html. Now, maybe I haven't understood what you're asking. Please elaborate.